# Family of zeros of polynomials

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, polynomials, fields

Let $k$ be an infinite field and $P(X_1,\dots,X_n)\in k[t][X_1,\dots, X_{n}]$, suppose that there exists a finite field extension $L$ of $k$ such that 
$P(x'_1,\dots,x'_n)\in L[t]^{*}=L^{*}$ with $x'_i\in L$.

Can we find $(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in k^{n}$ such that $P(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in k[t]^{*}=k^{*}$

Comment: What is $K$ in your question?

Answer (score 3):

Is $K=k$? If so, then the answer is clearly no. For example, $P(X)=(X^2+1)t+1$ and $k=\mathbb{R}$ and $L=\mathbb{C}$. Then $P(i)=1\in{L}^*=\mathbb{C}^*$, but there is no $x\in{k}=\mathbb{R}$ with $P(x)\in{k}^*=\mathbb{R}^*$.